Defining a device with multiple topics with Fiware-IoTAgent
I have a sensor device. There are 2 topics under this sensor device. I want to listen to the topics and sensor attributes of this sensor device using fiware-iotagentjson. But I don't know how to send a request to fiware-iotagentjson for this device.
I use this docker-compose.yml:
version: "3.8"
services:
  # Orion is the context broker
  orion:
    image: fiware/orion:${ORION_VERSION}
    hostname: orion
    container_name: fiware-orion-pms
    networks:
      - default
    expose:
      - "${ORION_PORT}"
    ports:
      - "${ORION_PORT}:${ORION_PORT}" # localhost:1026
    command: -dbhost ${IP_ADDRESS}:27030 -logLevel DEBUG -mqttTimeout ${ORION_MQTT_TIMEOUT} -t 255
    environment:
      - ORION_LOG_DEPRECATE=true 
    healthcheck:
      test: curl --fail -s http://orion:${ORION_PORT}/version || exit 1
      interval: 5s
    restart: always
iot-agent:
    image: fiware/iotagent-json:3.3.0
    hostname: iot-agent
    container_name: fiware-iot-agent-pms
    networks:
      - default
    expose:
      - "${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}"
    ports:
      - "${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}:${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}" # localhost:4041
    environment:
      - IOTA_CB_HOST=${IP_ADDRESS} # name of the context broker to update context
      - IOTA_CB_PORT=1026 # port the context broker listens on to update context
      - IOTA_NORTH_PORT=4041
      - IOTA_REGISTRY_TYPE=mongodb #Whether to hold IoT device info in memory or in a database
      - IOTA_LOG_LEVEL=DEBUG # The log level of the IoT Agent
      - IOTA_TIMESTAMP=true # Supply timestamp information with each measurement
      - IOTA_CB_NGSI_VERSION=v2 # use NGSIv2 when sending updates for active attributes
      - IOTA_AUTOCAST=true # Ensure Ultralight number values are read as numbers not strings
      - IOTA_MONGO_HOST=${IP_ADDRESS} # The host name of MongoDB
      - IOTA_MONGO_PORT=27030 # The port mongoDB is listening on
      - IOTA_MONGO_DB=iotagentul # The name of the database used in mongoDB
      - IOTA_MQTT_HOST=${MQTT_HOST} # The host name of the MQTT Broker
      - IOTA_MQTT_PORT=1883 # The port the MQTT Broker is listening on to receive topics
      - IOTA_DEFAULT_RESOURCE=
      - IOTA_PROVIDER_URL=http://iot-agent:${IOTA_NORTH_PORT}
      - IOTA_DEFAULT_TRANSPORT=MQTT
    healthcheck:
      interval: 5s
    restart: always
networks:
  default:
    labels:
      org.fiware: 'fiware-networks-pms'
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: 172.50.1.0/24


If I have a device like below:
test:CD99{
ENV
Data ={  
"OT_LOW_BUFF_RESET_CNT": 0,
  "COAP_AA": 0,
  "NRFX_AA": 28,
 }
}


I use the following curl for the device given above and similar and the device is registered to mongo successfully. Curl is:
curl --location 'http://192.168.2.205:4041/iot/devices' \
--header 'fiware-service: acd' \
--header 'fiware-servicepath: /pa/DEVICE31' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
 "devices": [
   {
     "device_id": "PA_DEVICE31",
     "entity_name": "PA_DEVICE31",
     "entity_type": "pa",
     "transport":   "HTTP",
     "timezone":    "Europe/Istanbul",
     "attributes": [
       { "object_id": "Voltage_UL1_N", "name":"Voltage_UL1_N", "type":"Double"}
      ],
      "static_attributes": [
         {"name":"refStore", "type": "Relationship","value": "urn:ngsi-ld:pa_device31:001"}
      ],
       "explicitAttrs": true
       
   }
 ]
}'

mongo data:

I currently have a device that comes in the following json structure. There are 2 topics under this device. There are sensors under every topic.
test:CD99{
ENV
Data ={  
"OT_LOW_BUFF_RESET_CNT": 0,
  "COAP_AA": 0,
  "NRFX_AA": 28,
}
RSSI
Data={
{
  "DA1C1C": "-37",
  "000000": "0"
}
}


If I have a device with the above data structure, how should I prepare a curl for this device?

That payload has no sense to me. Which iotAgent are you using? Have you provisioned a device group / apykey? What do you mean by “threads” are you talking about runtime execution?

I made the question clearer and more organized. Can you look again?
